# change entity connection on the fly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection

I am using C# 4.0. (Winform Application)
I have a code like this:

```
private bool ChangeEFConnectionString(string connStringName, string newValue)
{
    try
    {
        //CreateXDocument and load configuration file
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

        //Find all connection strings
        var query1 = from p in doc.Descendants("connectionStrings").Descendants()
                     select p;

        //Go throught each connection string elements find atribute specified by argument and replace its value with newVAlue  
        foreach (var child in query1)
        {
            foreach (var atr in child.Attributes())
            {
                if (atr.Name.LocalName == "name" && atr.Value == connStringName)
                    if (atr.NextAttribute != null && atr.NextAttribute.Name == "connectionString")
                    {
                        // Create the EF connection string from existing 
                        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
                            new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(atr.NextAttribute.Value);
                        //change hte provide conn string
                        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = newValue;
                        //back the full connection string to the configuration fiel
                        atr.NextAttribute.Value = entityBuilder.ToString();
                    }
            }
        }

        doc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works well, but somehow it not work any more.

As I debug it : `entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = newValue;` had the right value
but it still not change the connectionstring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) for reading and updating connection strings:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[connStringName].ConnectionString = newValue;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Comment: it work, but when i restart the application it still got the old connectionstring.

Comment: @user1958628 you are restarting application from Visual Studio?

Comment: @user1958628 Visual Studio replaces your modified config file with default one from project. Run `exe` file instead and attach debugger to application process

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is, after the `Save`, a:

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Have you considered giving EF the whole connection string instead of the name? That would keep you from having to modify what the name means at run time.